# Google sheets imported text with white spaces and unwanted paragraphs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm importing data with importxml but i get white spaces on the form of paragraph not present in the original text (img 1)

Attention! This happens only when i wrap text. In Overflow or Clip is ok.

I have tried this `=substitute` and `=trim` and

```
=replace \n and @style= and =REGEXREPLACE

=importxml("website"; "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/article/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]")
```

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(...); CHAR(10); ))
```

Comment: Thnx but i already tried with char and n and gives me Formula parse error. Just shared link of doc

Comment: instead of commas , use semicolons ; that will solve your parse error problems

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula then try to wrap text:

```
=regexreplace(index(importxml("https://guidatvoggi.it/stasera-in-tv", "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/article/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]"),3),"\s+"," ")
```